# CSS code while using form_for in rails to modify the textfield size

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using form_for in rails to create a user form to sign-in. I am not using bootstrap to format the form. I would like to change the size of the text field box in the form. Can any suggest me with the css code of that?

Answer (score 3):

You would use something like this if you want to edit all the input-text elements.

```
 form input[type='text'] {
   width: 100px;
   height: 30px;
 }
```

Else you also could use

```
#user_email {
  your styling;
}
```

Or, you also can attach a custom class to your text field via

```
f.text_field :email, :class => 'login-email-field'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe you could try something like:

In ruby:

```
<%= form_for @client do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :request, class: "client-request" %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

In CSS:

```
.client-request {
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

What about?

Comment: Your CSS would only work with this: `<%= f.text_field :request, class: "client-request" %>`.

Comment: Unless you meant this for the CSS: `#client_request { ... }`. I probably wouldn't do that in case that id gets used elsewhere though.